# change two bits by using only bitwise operations

Tags: binary

try to write shortest possible variant of logic which converts binary input by this table:

```
00 -> 00
01 -> 10
10 -> 01
11 -> 11
```

You can use only bitwise and bitshift operations. I calculate only operations and don't care brackets, spaces, constants and etc. But you can't use any control (if, while, ternary) and arithmetic operations.

If you are using bitwise and bitshift operations, your operations number will be multipled by two:

```
op_num = (your_op_num << types_of_operation_num) >> 1
```

**edit: sorry, this is not real code-golf, because I calculate operations in logic, not characters.**

Comment: In x86 assembly, I think `rol` would do this in one instruction (if it could operate on only 2 bits).

Comment: Ok, so how do we count score exactly? One or two examples, maybe?

Comment: The problem is: With only bitwise operators, you can't combine numbers. And the bitwise operators can only affect bits at the same position. (`1x & 1y` - x and y can't affect the result of the first bit.). So every logic based solution has to use both of them.

Comment: I offer a boonty of 50 rep for the first solution that uses only bitwise operators or bitshift operators that operate on inifite range.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Infinite range? The question is about 2 bit numbers, isn't it? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I don't like to see solutions like `i<<1` and claiming that it does roate without carry on a 2-bit space.

Comment: It's pretty trivial to show that this cannot be done with bitwise operators alone. You have to use at least one bitshift operator (since arithmetic and other operators are forbidden).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 6 operations

```
216>>i>>i&3
```

Same idea:

```
216>>(i<<1)&3
```

Answer (score 4):

### 8 operations (4 * 2)

Ok, here a real answer:

```
(i&1)<<1|i>>1
```

Comment: I think meant is, use as less different and total operators as possible.

Comment: Because using and bitshift operations is much more easiest.

Comment: Who knows? It is tagged as [tag:code-golf] so characters/bytes should count.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Yup definetly tagged wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I don't read carefull. This is not real code-golf.

Answer (score 3):

**Javascript, 0 operators**

```
alert(prompt().split('').reverse().join(''))
```

Comment: This is [tag:code-golf]. Characters count.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I was confused, [tag:codegolf] vs `If you are using bitwise and bitshift operations, your operations number will be multipled by two:`

Answer (score 1):

### Tcl, 0 operators

```
string rev $i
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica 0 operators?

If a string, `s`, is input, any of the following should work:

```
StringReverse[s]

StringRotateLeft[s]

StringRotateRight[s]
```

If the input is a list of digits (the standard way to represent binary digits in Mathematica), this will work:

```
(# /. {{0,1} -> {1,0}, {1,0} -> {0,1}}) &
```